# How to make the program know two items are touching each other? Python/tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to be able to add many gates to the canvas but when they touch the output or input lines the program knows that they are touching and outputs a message, for example "and gate is connected to and gate".
This is the code for the inserting the gates to the canvas. I have tried making the input/output lines as different tags that recognise each other but that did not work. Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
from tkinter import *

canvas=Canvas(width=600,height=600)
canvas.grid()

gate_id = 0
def andGATE():
    global gate_id
    gate_id += 1
    gate_tag = "andgate-%s" % gate_id
    tags = ("andgate", gate_tag)

    canvas.create_line(150, 50, 150, 150, width=5, tags=tags)
    canvas.create_arc(150, 50, 200, 150, start=90, extent=-180, width=5, fill="black", tags=tags)

    canvas.create_line(150, 75, 120, 75, width=5, tags=tags)
    canvas.create_line(150, 120, 120, 120, width=5, tags=tags)
    canvas.create_line(200, 100, 250, 100, width=5, tags=tags)
    canvas.create_rectangle(150, 50, 180, 150, width=5, fill="black", tags=tags)

    canvas.tag_bind(gate_tag, "<B1-Motion>", lambda event, tag=gate_tag: moveANDGate(event, tag))

def gateSelected():
    sf=var.get()
    if sf=='AND':
        andGATE()


def moveANDGate(event, tag):
    x=event.x
    y=event.y
    coords=canvas.coords(tag)
    movex=x-coords[0]
    movey=y-coords[1]
    canvas.move(tag, movex, movey)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
var = StringVar(root)
var.set('AND')
choices = ['AND']
option = OptionMenu(root, var, *choices)
option.pack(side="left",padx=10,pady=10)
button = Button(root, text="Add Gate", command=gateSelected)
button.pack(side="left",padx=10,pady=10)
clearButton = Button(root,text="Clear",command=lambda:clearScreen())
clearButton.pack(side="left",padx=30,pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't have a complete answer but I do have a concept that may work. Create an extra canvas line item (1 pixel in size) at the end of each of the and gate input/output ports. Give these items a tag like "input" "output". When you move the gates, check to see if any of the inputs of a gate are close to the outputs of another gate. If the distance between the two is zero then you have a connection. You could also do an item "snap" if they are within a few pixels of the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a complete answer but a workable step in the right direction for you.

```
from tkinter import *

gate_id = 0
def andGATE():
    global gate_id
    gate_id += 1
    gate_tag = "andgate-%s" % gate_id
    tags = ("andgate", gate_tag)
    inputs = ("andgate", gate_tag, "input")
    outputs = ("andgate", gate_tag, "output")

    canvas.create_line(150, 50, 150, 150, width=5, tags=tags)
    canvas.create_arc(150, 50, 200, 150, start=90, extent=-180, width=5, fill="black", tags=tags)

    canvas.create_line(150, 75, 120, 75, width=5, tags=tags)
    canvas.create_line(150, 120, 120, 120, width=5, tags=tags)

    canvas.create_line(200, 100, 250, 100, width=5, tags=tags)
    #End of output
    canvas.create_line(250,100,245,100, width=5, fill="red", tags=outputs)
    #End of inputs
    canvas.create_line(150, 75, 120, 75, width=5, tags=tags)
    canvas.create_line(120, 75, 125, 75, width=5, fill="blue", tags=inputs)
    canvas.create_line(120, 120, 125, 120, width=5, fill="blue", tags=inputs)

    canvas.create_rectangle(150, 50, 180, 150, width=5, fill="black", tags=outputs)

    canvas.tag_bind(gate_tag, "<B1-Motion>", lambda event, tag=gate_tag: moveANDGate(event, tag))

def gateSelected():
    sf=var.get()
    if sf=='AND':
        andGATE()


def moveANDGate(event, tag):
    x=event.x
    y=event.y
    coords=canvas.coords(tag)
    movex=x-coords[0]
    movey=y-coords[1]
    canvas.move(tag, movex, movey)
    #print("Move")

    #Determine if we have an overlap between an input and an output
    for item in canvas.find_all():
        tags = canvas.gettags(item)
        if tag in tags:
            if 'input' in tags:
                #current item is an input of the moved object
                #Get the items coordinates
                coords = canvas.coords(item)
                #Find if we overlap with other objects
                closest = canvas.find_overlapping(coords[0],coords[1],coords[2],coords[3])
                for closest_items in closest:
                    closest_tags = canvas.gettags(closest_items)
                    if 'output' in closest_tags:
                        #If we overlap with another object, print connected and the appropriate tags
                        print("connected", closest_tags, "-", tag)




root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
canvas=Canvas(root,width=300,height=300)
canvas.pack()
var = StringVar(root)
var.set('AND')
choices = ['AND']
option = OptionMenu(root, var, *choices)
option.pack(side="left",padx=10,pady=10)
button = Button(root, text="Add Gate", command=gateSelected)
button.pack(side="left",padx=10,pady=10)
#clearButton = Button(root,text="Clear",command=calculate)
#clearButton.pack(side="left",padx=30,pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

When ever an object is moved, the code looks to find whether one of the input ports of the shape we just moved, overlaps with an output port. If an overlap is found, we output "connected".
You may wish to extend what I've done to add a port ID to each input port so that you can differentiate which input in connected to the output of the other gate.

I've added blue rectangles for inputs and red rectangles for outputs but you can change the color of these as they are just intended to be hidden markers. You can also change the size of these markers if you find the connection to be too sensitive.

You may find the tkinterbook documentation for canvas to be helpful (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm).

To 'snap' the two components together when they get close to each other, you can change the section of code inside the moveANDGate function to the following

```
#Determine if we have an overlap between an input and an output
for item in canvas.find_all():
    tags = canvas.gettags(item)
    if tag in tags:
        if 'input' in tags:
            #current item is an input of the moved object
            #Get the items coordinates
            coords = canvas.coords(item)
            #Find if we overlap with other objects
            closest = canvas.find_overlapping(coords[0]-5,coords[1]-5,coords[2]+5,coords[3]+5)
            for closest_item in closest:
                closest_tags = canvas.gettags(closest_item)
                if 'output' in closest_tags:
                    #If we overlap with another object, print connected and the appropriate tags
                    print("connected", closest_tags, "-", tag)
                    connected_coords = canvas.coords(closest_item)
                    snapx = coords[0] - connected_coords[0]
                    snapy = coords[1] - connected_coords[1]
                    canvas.move(tag, -snapx, -snapy)
```

If the ports are within 5 pixels of each other, they will snap together. (this doesn't work hugely well at the moment with more than 2 gates.)